# Hibernate configuration for mapping XML and class for joining two tables

Tags: hibernate, inner-join, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate 3.3 on my Struts 2 web application. In my case, I've two tables `TABLE_A`, `TABLE_B` which are not mapped with any relationship. But there will be a column implicitly one-to-many between `TABLE_B` to `TABLE_A`. So while querying on it, I've to inner join on those those tables. I could do it by running HQL with inner join. My sample HQL query is as follows:

```
TABLE_A->TableA.java,TableA.hbm.xml
TABLE_B->TableB.java,TableB.hbm.xml
select tabA from com.test.db.TableA as tabA,com.test.db.TableB as tabB where (tabA.tableACommonCol=tabB.tableBCommonCol and tabB.tableBConstraint='value')
```

In the above query I've to put sorting, searching on different types of columns like `String`, `Timestamp`, `Long`...

Now what I'm trying to do is a common class which has the columns which are to be used to while querying or the references of these classes, and use that with criteria.

If it is possible, how should I configure the mapped class and `hbm.xml` files of `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`. If not, how can I achieve this?